# Python Tkinter: Quality of images drops when not using IDLE

Tags: python, image, tkinter, graphics

Lately I have been working on a simple interface in Tkinter. It renders some images and the quality of them is all fine if I use Visual Studio, or Pycharm or even the original python 3.7 IDLE. The problem here is that, if I use the cmd to call the app (I just call it via `python main.exe`)and add some images, the quality is totally diferent. I tried also compiling to exe via PyInstaller but the problem persists. I will add some images here as the code I am using to call the images. Any thoughs/ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
imgpath=PIL.Image.open("currentimg.png")
ph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imgpath)
x = Label(root, image=ph)
Label.image=ph 
x.place (height=392, width=280, y=50, x=20)
```

[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya8CP.png) [Img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GguYH.png)

Comment: It is hard to say why this is happening just from looking at the examples though.

Comment: @CoolCloud I edited the post so you can see the code. Thanks!

Comment: You are keeping a reference to image, but is it the correct way? Im not sure, try saying `x.image=ph` instead of `Label.image=ph`

Comment: @CoolCloud stills the same unfortunately

Comment: Hmmm its strange as to why this is happening.

Comment: @CoolCloud Yeah. I found nothing on the web, thats why I am asking :D

Comment: Maybe some problem with the compilation. Have you tried using using a different system?

Comment: @CoolCloud Linux, but everything is good there. I guess is something windows related but I can´t figure out what it is

Comment: Hmmmm, ive used images with windows and can confirm it works fine

Comment: @CoolCloud Hum...Maybe something is wrong with my distribution? When I got home I will try to reinstall it. If it does not work I guess I will have to try to reinstall windows completely

Comment: I dont think its the problem of Windows, though.

Comment: @CoolCloud It can be someting graphics related, I guess

Comment: Hmmmm, keep a link to the entire code

Comment: Its huge.Over 3k lines, and everything is connected,so kinda hard to check